# Как лучше слить два массива в один

Tags: php

Есть два массива: В первом массиве хранятся названия характеристик, во втором массиве хранятся их значения. Нужно их слить, что бы потом можно было вывести Названия характеристики и список их значений, ну как это правильно сделать пока еще не придумал. Дайте совет для простоты решения или может такой вариант не совсем будет удобен для манипуляции с выводом данных в виде списка или чекбокса.

```
 1. Массив характеристик:

        array(9) {
          [0]=>
          array(5) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["name_ru"]=>
            string(8) "Цвет"
            ["alias"]=>
            string(6) "colour"
            ["type"]=>
            string(6) "select"
          }
          [1]=> ...
        }  

    2. Массив значений 

        array(27) {
          [0]=>
          array(4) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["property_id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["value_ru"]=>
            string(14) "Красный"
          }
          [1]=> ....
        }  

    3.Предполагаемый массив
     array(9) {
          [0]=>
          array(5) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["name_ru"]=>
            string(8) "Цвет"
            ["alias"]=>
            string(6) "colour"
            ["type"]=>
            string(6) "select"
            ["values"] => 
                [0] => 
                    array(4) {
                        ["id"]=>
                        int(1)
                        ["property_id"]=>
                        int(1)
                        ["value_ru"]=>
                        string(14) "Красный"
                    }
                [1] => .....
          }
          [1]=> ...
        }
```

Comment: По какому признаку-то они должны объединяться?

Comment: В SO принято ответ оформлять как ответ — даже когда вы его сами даёте. Реактировать вопрос можно для исправления ошибок или уточнения условия.

Comment: Пока вы не оформите свой ответ, вопрос так и останется без принятого решения. Это плохо.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, что объединяться массивы должны по `id` в массиве характеристик? В таком случае, думаю, что `array_filter()`, то, что Вам нужно.

Прокручиваете массив характеристик применяя фильтр к массиву значений.

Что-то типа такого:
`$properties` - массив характеристик
`$values` - массив значений

```
for($i=0; $i<Count($properties); $i++) {
    $property_id = $properties[$i]["id"];
    $properties[$i]["values"] = array_filter($values,
        function($el) {
            if ($el["property_id"]==$property_id) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот код должен добавить значения к исходному массиву атрибутов:

```
array_walk(
    $attributes,
    function(&$item, $key) use($values) {
        $item += [ 'values' => $values[$key] ];
    }
);
```

Здесь я исхожу из того, что склейка происходит по простому индексу массива.

Update: Как внезапно выяснилось, записи связаны по `id`-`property_id`:

```
array_walk(
    $attributes,
    function(&$item) use($values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['property_id'] == $item['id']) break;
        }
        $item += ['values' => $values[$key]];
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, сделал вот так:

```
 private function mmarge_array($array, $array_value){
        $newArray = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            $newArray[$i] = array(
                'id' => $array[$i]['id'],
                'name' => $array[$i]['name'],
                'alias' => $array[$i]['alias'],
                'type' => $array[$i]['type'],
            );

            for ($j  = 0; $j < count($array_value); $j++) {
                if ($array[$i]['id'] == $array_value[$j]['property_id']) {
                    $newArray[$i]['values'][] = array(
                        'id' => $array_value[$j]['id'],
                        'value' => $array_value[$j]['value'],
                    );
                }
            }

        }

        return $newArray;
}
```